# Downloading docx file in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have uploaded the docx file, then i want to download docx file, when i go to download then some problem arise, problem are shown in picture below

[image]

[image]

My code look like this

```
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseBase DownloadMapCyclo(Int32 CourseInfoCycloID = -1)
        {
            try
            {
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;filename=file.docx");
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
                Response.OutputStream.Write(byteArrays, 0, byteArrays.Length);
                return Response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Output.WriteLine("<h1>" + ex.Message + "</h1><br/><hr/>" + ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
                return Response;
            }
        }
```

Do you have any solution for this downloading..thanks

Comment: 1) Are you sure the file is being returned and not that exception message?  2) Why not just `return File()` as an `ActionResult` instead of using the `Response` object?

Comment: Hi @David, Ok, let me try

Comment: you are returning response, return file

Comment: File(contents, "application/docx", "PropsedChanges.docx");

Comment: Hi @David, your answer is right, you can post your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing to the `Response` object (and thereby coupling your code with an active HTTP context), simply return an `ActionResult` form the method and use [the `File()` helper method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470835(v=vs.118).aspx) to respond with a file.

```
public ActionResult DownloadMapCyclo(Int32 CourseInfoCycloID = -1)
{
    //...
    return File(byteArrays, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "file.docx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your Return Type is `response` change it to `file` type

`File(byteArrays, "application/docx", "PropsedChanges.docx");`